# Do I need i18next-xhr-backend for using translations in separated json files?

Tags: html, i18next

I'm using i18next in a pure html website.

Here is error message:

> i18next::translator: missingKey en translation title title

Here is the code:

```
 ///multilng.js
(function () {


i18next
.init({
    "debug": true,
    "lng": "en",
    "ns": [
      "translation"
    ],
    "fallbackLng": false,
    "keySeparator": false,
    "nsSeparator": false,
    resources: {
      "backend": {
        "loadPath": "../locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json"
      }
    }
  }, function(err, t) {
   console.log(err);
 });

  function changeLng(lng) {
    i18next.changeLanguage(lng);
  }

  i18next.on('languageChanged', () => {
    updateContent();
  });

  updateContent();
})();

function updateContent() {
  var title = i18next.t("title");
  $("#logo.dark-logo").html(title);
}
```

Here is the project structure:

[image]

Here is how I reference the js files:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/vendor/i18next.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-i18next/1.1.0/jquery-i18next.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/i18nextXhr.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/main.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/multilng.js'></script>
```

Here is the content of a translation.json:

```
{
    "title":"My Studio",
    "slogan":"Your expert."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like to load them via xhr - yes. There are other options like bundling them or custom backends, the list is endless: https://www.i18next.com/overview/plugins-and-utils

Or creating a own implementation: https://www.i18next.com/misc/creating-own-plugins

The one misconfiguration i spot in your options is that backend options are nested in resources...those should be on top level plus do not add resources on init if you like to load them.

Comment: Thanks jamuhl, as you can see the project structure, I have these 2 json files in the project, so I do not need to make any xhr call to get them. All I need to do is to load my translations in different files. Please help

Comment: Hi Jamuhl,  could you please spare some time on this one as well? thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50829199/how-to-use-i18next-on-my-whole-website

Comment: you can directly import them on init as options.resources https://www.i18next.com/overview/getting-started#basic-sample or use the functions: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resource-handling to include them