# How to use i18next to localise my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, i18next

I have a very simple website with no backend, just pure html pages.

I need to have English/Chinese versions for this website, what I need to achieve is have a button on NavBar, when users click this button, the wording on entire website will be changed to Chinese/English.

All the examples I have seen that they are all require something like this:

```
localize(".nav");
```

So does it mean that I need to do something like this:

```
localize("body");
```

in order to get the whole website language switched?

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc here is the list of [supported-frameworks](https://www.i18next.com/overview/supported-frameworks). As your project is a basic HTML one you should use this https://github.com/mthh/loc-i18next. When you init the module on a TAG you should me make sure there is the `data-i18n="myKey"` attribute with the key of string that need to be translated. So `localize("body");` should translate the whole body but you must add the `data-i18n` attribute to each tag with a string key

Comment: @Franva as you asked: this is the correct reply...or use https://github.com/i18next/i18nextify